# Snowflake date_trunc to remove time from date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have snowflake column which contains date in yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss format.

I use the below function

```
 date_trunc('DAY', '2019-09-23 12:33:25')
```

Output : `2019-09-23 00:00:00`

Expected as per [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html#examples) : `2019-09-23`

Is it a bug or is there any other way to remove the time component altogether ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what you're wanting to do with the date, having a midnight time is fine.

If you really must get rid of it, this will work:

```
cast(date_trunc('DAY', '2019-09-23 12:33:25') as date)
```

Comment: '2019-09-23 12:33:25'::date gives the same results but shorter

Comment: No need to truncate when you cast to a date.  This is like doing CAST(ROUND(3.14) AS INTEGER)

Answer (score 3):

date_trunc as the documentation say, truncates a timestamp to values on different grain. But the result is still a timestamp, thus the output format.

if you want just the truncated date, casting to `date` as cmcau mentions is a simple way to go. But if you are casting to `date` there is no need to truncate as they are the same value, thus `'2019-09-23 12:33:25'::date` should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

In certain environments like Mode Analytics, casting to date like some of the other answers mention still displays a `00:00:00` on the end. If this is the case and you are only using the date for display purposes, you can take your truncated date and cast it to `varchar` instead like this: `'2019-09-23 12:33:25'::date::varchar`

Note, I would only recommend this if the other answers are not working for you.