# Does DATE_TRUNC Remove Data ? [POSTGRESQL]

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to use a sql query with **DATE_TRUNC()**. I saw that entry: [Snowflake date_trunc to remove time from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111744/snowflake-date-trunc-to-remove-time-from-date)
I tested on local docker containers. It worked fine. Just to be sure, does **trunc** remove/pop timestamps ? It's sound likes truncate :) Thanks for your time.
i.e

```
SELECT
       DATE_TRUNC('month',production_timestamp)
         AS  production_to_month,
       COUNT(id) AS count
FROM watch
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month',production_timestamp);
```

I want to calculate the monthly number of data in a column. With out update any data.

Comment: Remove timestamps from where? What is "pop"?

Comment: What did the manual tell you about this function?

Comment: The output of the function is truncated to the level specified, it does not truncate/change the value in the database field. If you want it to end up as date then: `DATE_TRUNC('month',production_timestamp)::date`.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

It truncates a timestamp to the accuracy you specify, returning that new value. It doesn't change any data in tables.